# Hibernate query - How to select those parents that have ALL the children matching a value?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to write a Hibernate (JPA) query to select those parents where **ALL** their children match a property.

Let's make a pratical example...

I want to select those fathers who have **ALL** their children blond. If just one is black haired the father is not selected.

How will the query look like?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
From Father f
where not exists (select c from f.children c where not c.hair = "BLONDE");
```

Just an idea...

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the `ALL`
see http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.1.0/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_all_any:

```
select p from parent where 'blonde'=all(parent.children.haircolor)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work and it looks a bit cleaner.

```
SELECT p from Parent p join p.children c where c.haircolor = 'blonde';
```